# Remove icon space from TabHost

Tags: android, android-tabhost, tabwidget, tabview

I need to remove the space between text and top border. I want it to be aligned to center.

Now my TabHost looks like this

[image]

I need to convert into something like this
[image]

My styles.xml

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:tabWidgetStyle">@style/LightTabWidget</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#0767de</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar1" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
</style>

<style name="LightTabWidget" parent="@android:style/Widget.TabWidget">
    <!-- set textColor to red, so you can verify that it applied. -->
    <item name="android:textColor">#0767de</item>w
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:tabStripEnabled">false</item>
</style>
```

Thanks in advance